# Call write function, which doesn't change contract value

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, ether

I'm new in smart contracts and faced with one problem.
After deploying contract to my test local blockchain network, i try to set new value via setter, after that I call get method of contract and it return old value.

This is my contract,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Storage {
    uint256 storedData;

    function set(uint256 data) {
        storedData = data;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint256) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

What steps I did:

1. Deploy contract via web3j in java code, after deploying I see address of my contract,so it's deployed
2. After than in geth console create variable abi: 
   var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"data","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"statemutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"statemutability":"view","type":"function"}];
3. load contract: var storage = eth.contract(abi)
4. load contract by adress: var contractInstance = storage.at("0x45564fe8d90e542f3f896dd43b374210bc109299");
5. try calling method get(): var result = contractInstance.get();
   it's output **0**
6. then try set new value: var result = contractInstance.set(566);
   After that I see something like this: 
   INFO [09-07|08:42:07] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x7110b3fdfc8005187ed367beb8275a6f4b926f4852f726784219a5a3aa9c8d9e recipient=0x45564fe8d90e542f3f896dd43b374210bc109299
   "0x7110b3fdfc8005187ed367beb8275a6f4b926f4852f726784219a5a3aa9c8d9e"
7. Next I start mining: miner.start(), at the beginning of mining a see log like this: INFO [09-07|08:44:15] Commit new mining work                   number=38 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=1.044ms
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15] Successfully sealed new block            number=38 hash=e62548…39ad89
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15]  block reached canonical chain          number=33 hash=9a6ae1…9cb82d
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15]  mined potential block                  number=38 hash=e62548…39ad89
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15] Commit new mining work                   number=39 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=182.5µs
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15] Successfully sealed new block            number=39 hash=87b682…f52e39
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15]  block reached canonical chain          number=34 hash=cc9a2d…36838a
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15]  mined potential block                  number=39 hash=87b682…f52e39
   INFO [09-07|08:44:15] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
8. Then I stop mining: miner.stop()
   9.Then call contractInstance.get(): and see the same value **0**

I'm confused( 
Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: Your code is correct, and i test everything is ok. do you confirm mining is success?

Comment: @BinGoBinBin I think yes. There is my log, when I start mining.                             Starting mining operation
INFO [09-06|18:10:01] Commit new mining work                   number=1400 txs=6 uncles=0 elapsed=1.092ms
INFO [09-06|18:10:01] Successfully sealed new block            number=1400 hash=8cd59b…0bb28c
INFO [09-06|18:10:01]  block reached canonical chain          number=1395 hash=81696a…5fc7fa
INFO [09-06|18:10:01]  mined potential block                  number=1400 hash=8cd59b…0bb28c

Comment: Can you add the exact way you're calling these functions through web3? Also, between miner.start() and calling these functions, you should see something like "Transaction added to pool". Can you confirm that you see something like that?

Comment: @wtk219 I update my question, and provide more detailed steps that I did.

Comment: Try giving `storedData` a default value before you try to change it, that will tell you whether your problem is the reading or the writing.

Comment: @EdmundEdgar added default value, it still returns **0**, I thinks problems is in web3j library, seems like it incorrect create wrapper for smart contract

Comment: @EdmundEdgar I even alter function get, that it return literal(256), but it still return 0, maybe it some bug in contract version or some tricky issue, I'm really confused

Comment: General advices: 1. Use recent solidity version, 2. Do not forget the `constructor()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use below Commands:

> storage.get.call()
>   0
>   storage.set.sendTransaction(42, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000})
>   "0x7a54ab329fcbf551432eb78c4b2a1ff48fc8b9f9aa23d94fa86330e5c1d711f3"
>   storage.get.call()
>   42

**Reference Link:** https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/deploying-a-smart-contract-the-hard-way-8aae778d4f2a